# Size of text (Title, label, left stats, etc.)

Tags: androidplot

The text size of the text labels is really small. I tried to look on how to enlarge it in LineAndPointFormatter or XYPlot but found nothing. How can I do it? [image]

See that it the picture, I have "Percent", "Game #" and "Correct Characters" labels but they are barely readable (and also the stats 0.0, 22.2, 44.4, 66.7, 88.9);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the image above, you may be using a really old version of Androidplot.  If you upgrade to 1.x and apply a default style to your plot as described in the [quickstart tutorial](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md), these issues should disappear.